# How to make the wix file compilation success using wix toolset nuget package?

Tags: c#, cakebuild

Am new to `C#` `cake build`.

I need to create a `WiX installer` using `WiX nuget package`.

I have included the `WiX nuget package` in my cake script.

Packages downloaded properly. But, `WiX` file getting error that some `WiX` related files were not referred properly from `WiX` installation location.

So, i have moved the required files from `WiX toolset nuget package` download location to the `Program Files (x86)` folder like the files installed through `WiX installer`.

Now am getting the compilation error that `WiX` related files not found from Program Files (x86) due to the registry entry for `WiX` is not made.

Could anyone please share me the information to made the registry entry for `WiX` from cake script file?

Thanks in advance for your help and suggestions.

Comment: Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Can you provide (perhaps using a gist) the build.cake file that you are using?